# Getting forbidden error from code downloading image from web

Tags: python, function, urllib, urlretrieve

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download_web_image(url):
  name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
  full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

download_web_image("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A few websites do not allow  to download images from there website. There are ways to pretend like a browser. Explore it

Answer (score 0):

A more compatible method using the request module would be the following:

```
import random
import requests

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(f'C:\\Test\\{full_name}', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.content)

download_web_image("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg")
```

Also be sure to modify `f'C:\\Test\\{full_name}'` to your desired output file path. And be sure to note the imported module changed from `import urllib.request` to `import requests`.